# Определение переменной среды для mercurial в Windows 7

Tags: windows, mercurial, windows-7

Нигде не могу найти в инете (гуглил долго, видно руки кривые), как мне для Windows (в данном случае для Windows 7) определить переменную среды в свойствах моего компьютера, чтобы в консоли мог писать просто hg.

Когда я установил Mercurial, у меня в path добавилась строка `C:\Program Files\Mercurial` 
и всё, но писать `hg <команда>` я не могу.

Приходится переходить в папку `C:\Program Files\Mercurial` и оттуда уже писать `hg`. Что нужно прописать и где в переменных среды (окружения)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательно посмотрите на несколько моментов

1. действительно ли hg.exe находится в самом каталоге `C:\Program Files\Mercurial`
2. `C:\Program Files\Mercurial` и `"C:\Program Files\Mercurial"` - не одно и то же. Все-таки путь содержит символ пробела, а по умолчанию он считается одним из разделителей.
3. Еще неплохо полностью привести содержимое переменной окружения PATH. Их, кстати, несколько. Одна глобальная, вторая - для конкретного пользователя. Изменяются где-то в недрах апплета свойства системы.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, завтра буду на работе - отвечу

Comment: 1) да, hg.exe находится в каталоге C:\Program Files\Mercurial
2)3) в PATH у меня:
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\

Comment: Попробуйте с кавычками.

Comment: спасибо большое! заработало!